# Can you see black holes?

Tags: black-holes

So I was arguing with someone whether it's possible or not to see a black hole.

Now, I know it's not possible to see it when in space (unless it sucks matter) but my question is whether or not it will be possible if, for example, we were to put one in front of a white screen.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "see", you can "see" a black hole by its effect on surrounding objects. If you put it in front of a white screen you'd still know something was there.

Comment: Can you see a shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A black hole appears, as the name suggests, black. This is because they absorb all light and don't emit any. So as you already said, when compared to the black background of space, they are invisible unless they are surrounded by an [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk). This is also how the famous picture of a black hole by the EHT was taken:

[image]

<sup>([Source](https://www.eso.org/public/images/eso1907a/))</sup>

The orange-ish ring that you see is, obviously, not the black hole itself – it is matter surrounding the black hole which emits light. One is however able to "see" the black hole in the middle<sup>1</sup> because there, the light from the accretion disk is blocked by the black hole. Similarly, you would be able to "see" a black hole in front of a white wall because it would block the white light reflected from the wall, thus creating a circular black "shadow".

---

<sup>1</sup> The black region doesn't correspond to the black hole itself, but its shadow – about 2.5 times of the event horizon.

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases to consider: case 1 where the mass is large enough that you can ignore Hawking radiation, and case 2 where Hawking radiation is significant and detectable by the human eye.

In either case you can tell where the black hole is from the received pattern of light, and thus "see" the black hole.

In case 1 you will see a circular region which is darker than the rest. There will also be a brighter region around it I think, owing to lensing effects. This type of situation can be used to detect a small black hole if it passes in front of a larger star (a large enough star would provide a roughly uniform background "screen").

In case 2 you will see the Hawking radiation.

Comment: @safesphere I think you are confusing two different mathematical issues: how to understand gravity in full (which presumably involves quantum theory), and how to do ordinary quantum field theory on a curved spacetime background. The latter is sufficiently well established to warrant this answer, IMO. Indeed the main facts about Hawking radiation can be derived via the Unruh effect, and a related spin effect (Sokolov-Ternov effect) has been observed in storage rings.